# How to write a method to read JSON files of different structures and return different POJO objects in Java?

Tags: java, json, interface, abstract-class

I have multiple JSON files of different structures, to read through my program.  For example,

issue.json:

```
 [
  {
   category : "self-help",
   count :268         
  },
  {
   category : "fiction",
   count :268         
  }  
 ]
```

user.json:

```
[
  {
     userId:1,
     userName:"Sam"
     bookId:[1,2,4]
  },
  {
     userId:123,
     userName:"Ram"
     bookId:[12,45,46]
  }

 ]
```

I have separate POJO classes to handle each JSON. I have  a file reader class which is used to read csv files, text files, json files etc. I want to create a way for json file reading alone, so that it could be used to read different files and return different POJO objects. Should I go ahead with abstract class or interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use interfaces

```
public interface JSONable{
     String toString();
     //other common methods
}

public Pojo1 implements JSONable{
     public String toString(){
       super.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your rationale for suggesting this?

Comment: I am assuming op is working with jdk 6/7 and just the principles of an interface.and this definition in oracle:

**Implementing an interface allows a class to become more formal about the behavior it promises to provide. Interfaces form a contract between the class and the outside world, and this contract is enforced at build time by the compiler**

An abstract class really would not fit here would it?